# query optimization (nested subqueries)

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I try to simplify below subqueries to improve select statement. I have table with 3 basic columns as ID, GRAGE and AGE. To select all records which have GRADE same as GRADE of Maximum ID
Might somebody have better way that create nested subqueries, welcome all your suggestions?

Note: My apologise for formatting the table

```
ID    GRADE     AGE
10      A           30
12      B           45
13      A           15
09      B           14
20      A           12
```

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    TABLE
WHERE
    GRADE = (
        SELECT
            grade
        FROM
            TABLE
        WHERE
            id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM TABLE)
    );
```

Comment: If you ask for perfromance optimization of this query, then please run `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR  your_query`, then `SELECT * FROM table( DBMS_XPLAN.Display )`, and finally copy a result of the latter query **as a text - not a bitmap** and append it to the question.

Comment: @krokodilko And I would add that the answer might also depend on how big the table is.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a CTE to make the query easier to read:

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT GRADE,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID DESC) RowNum
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE GRADE = (SELECT t.GRADE FROM cte t WHERE t.RowNum = 1)
```

However, I don't have a problem with your original approach because the subqueries are not correlated to anything.  What I mean by this is that

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM yourTable
```

should effectively only be executed once, and afterwards sort of be treated as a constant.  Similarly, the query

```
SELECT grade FROM TABLE WHERE id = (max from above query)
```

should also be executed only once.  This assumes that the query optimizer is smart enough to figure this out, which it probably is.

Comment: Thanks you, MAX vs PARTITION which will give better perfomace?.

Comment: Both your approach and mine should require 2 full table scans.  Please run `EXPLAIN` on both queries and see for yourself which is faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following (not much simpler though):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    TABLE
WHERE
    GRADE IN (
        SELECT
            first_value (GRADE) over (ORDER BY id DESC)
        FROM
            TABLE
    )
```